# Parse Server Cloud Code afterSave's not working on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, parse-cloud-code, parse-server

I've created Cloud Code `afterSave` and `beforeSave` functions for my Parse Server which runs perfectly when I'm running my server locally. However, when I deploy to Elastic Beanstalk, the `afterSave` functions simply does not work. `beforeSave`'s do work.

I've tried following the advice here [this](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/1031#issuecomment-200234025) as well as multiple other random attempts without no success.

Example `afterSave` that does not work on Elastic Beanstalk:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Entry", function(request) {
  var entry = request.object;
  var user = request.user;
  user.increment("totalDistance", entry.get("totalDistance"));
  user.save();
});
```

Note: I can't figure out how to find/access my Elastic Beanstalk NodeJS logs anywhere or in any way?

Comment: Your logs are accessible from the AWS console

Comment: You can also run `eb logs` if you used the ebcli to deploy